# Is there a way to reference the same CTE inside a compiled query more than once in Linq2Db?

Tags: c#, .net-core, f#, abstract-syntax-tree, linq2db

Consider the following C# code:

```cs
CompiledQuery.Compile<IDataContext, int>((ctx, someId) =>
  ctx
    .GetTable<SomeTable>()
    .Where(x => x.SomeId == someId /* complex filtering here */)
    .AsCte("filtered")
    .Join(
      ctx.GetTable<AnotherTable>(),
      SqlJoinType.Left,
      (filtered, another) => filtered.Id == another.SomeId,
      (filtered, another) => new { filtered.Id, another.SomeInteger }
    )
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id, x => x.SomeInteger)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, Sum = DataExtensions.AsNullable(x.Sum()) })
    .AsCte("grouped")
)
```

Let's assume that this part of the query results in the following SQL generated  (PostgreSQL dialect used):

```sql
WITH filtered AS (
  SELECT "Id", "IntegerValue" FROM "SomeTable"
  WHERE "SomeId" = @some_id
), grouped AS (
  SELECT filtered."Id", SUM(another."SomeInteger") as "Sum"
  FROM filtered
  LEFT JOIN "AnotherTable" another
    ON filtered."Id" = another."SomeId"
  GROUP BY filtered."Id"
)
```

What I want is to continue this query to generate the final CTE like

```
SELECT filtered."Id" "FilteredId", grouped."Id" "GroupedId"
FROM grouped
INNER JOIN filtered /*LINQ problem here: "filtered" is not saved to a variable to reference it one more*/
  ON filtered."SomeInteger" = grouped."Sum" OR grouped."Sum" IS NULL
```

As could be seen from the comment in the example above, there is seemingly no way to reference `filtered` once it has already been used. So the question is: is there a way to reference `filtered` inside the last part of the query (after grouping)?

Work-arounds not including the second CTE usage (like window functions or subquery usage) are out of scope for this question.

As `Compile` method accepts an expression, the System.Linq.Expressions restrictions apply: no ref/out/async/await/ValueTuple etc. ValueTuple restriction may be worked around via F# tuples, though.

Expression tree AST rewrite may be considered if there is a way to make it help (I'm doing it anyways to convert nested lambdas from F# representation to the representation linq2db is expecting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CTE functionality in `linq2db` uses expression tree comparison to detect the same CTE in query, so you can repeat that by `ExpressionMethod` helper which injects lambda body into original query.

```cs
private static Func<IQueryable<SomeTable>, int, IQueryable<SomeTable>> _complexFilterFunc;

[ExpressionMethod(nameof(ComplexFilterImpl))]
private static IQueryable<SomeTable> ComplexFilter(IQueryable<SomeTable> query, int someId)
{
    _complexFilterFunc ??= ComplexFilterImpl().Compile();
    return _complexFilterFunc(query, someId);
}

private static Expression<Func<IQueryable<SomeTable>, int, IQueryable<SomeTable>>> ComplexFilterImpl()
{
    return (query, someId) => query
        .Where(x => x.SomeId == someId /* complex filtering here */)
        .AsCte("filtered");
}
```

And use this method in your compiled query. If input parameters are identical it will produce only one CTE.

```cs
CompiledQuery.Compile<IDataContext, int>((ctx, someId) =>
  ComplexFilter(ctx.GetTable<SomeTable>(), someId)
    .Join(
      ctx.GetTable<AnotherTable>(),
      SqlJoinType.Left,
      (filtered, another) => filtered.Id == another.SomeId,
      (filtered, another) => new { filtered.Id, another.SomeInteger }
    )
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id, x => x.SomeInteger)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, Sum = DataExtensions.AsNullable(x.Sum()) })
    .AsCte("grouped")
)
```

Test that in regular query, then you can move to compiled query implementation.